How to make a excel button that is clinked to a macro display a dynamic value
I have an excel button that is linked to a macro
I am wanting to have the button text itself display the current month based on the current date.
it's such a simple request, yet it seems to be so hard to find an answer
I researched extensively online without any luck.

see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000204/vba-how-to-change-the-button-text  And put the code that changes the caption in the Workbook_open event.

Like Scott mentioned above, you can use this in the Workbook.Open event:
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Buttons("Button 1").Text = Format(Date, "mmmm")
End Sub

If you wanted to use a different month format you can try one of the other specified options below.
Format(Date, "m")      '4
Format(Date, "mm")     '04
Format(Date, "mmm")    'Apr
Format(Date, "mmm")    'April

